# MYSQL root password reset error

Tags: mysql, ubuntu-12.04

Running a server on Ubuntu, and needed to reset the mysql root password. Here is what I usually do (which usually seems to work):

Stopping the mysql server:

```
/etc/init.d/mysql stop
```

Starting the mysql server without password:

```
mysqld_safe --skip-grant-tables &
```

The error after running the command above:

```
[1] 14459
forge@test:~/dev.test.com$ 150809 15:12:01 mysqld_safe Can't log to error log and syslog at the same time.  Remove all --log-error configuration options for --syslog to take effect.
150809 15:12:01 mysqld_safe Logging to '/var/log/mysql/error.log'.
150809 15:12:01 mysqld_safe A mysqld process already exists
```

Any ideas? I have never seen this before.

EDIT: It may be worth mentioning I am using Forge for deployment.

Comment: have you try killall mysq before ?

Answer (score 1):

You have to add the --skip-syslog option to the startup command, more details here:
[Mysqld-safe](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/mysqld-safe.html)

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that Forge seems to re-start mysql by default if you turn it off in the command line...

By going into Forge, I was able to turn it off using the user-interface (Stop Services) for the particular server.